# Identyfying Advertisements on a webpage using selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm working on a project that has to detect advertisements on a web page using selenium .
I tried understanding adblock plus code but couldn't understand much . I have taken a filter list and started pattern matching the DOM elements ids and classes with each entry in the filter list . This is taking a lot of time . Could some one please suggest an efficient way or improve the code .
Sample code snippet

```
WebDriver wd = new FirefoxDriver();

wd.get("http://celebslam.celebuzz.com/");

for ( WebElement e :  wd.findElements(By.tagName("div")) ) {
    for (String  add :list)
        if(e.getAttribute("id").toLowerCase().matches(".*"+add+".*"))
            System.out.println(e.getAttribute("id"));    
}
```

I'm doing the same for class attibute as well
sample List of patterns looks like this

```
list.add("zMSplacement3");
list.add("zMSplacement4");
list.add("zoneAdvertisment");
list.add("zone_b_ad");
list.add("zone_c_ads");
```

Using around 1500 patterns to identify all advertisements tags.

Comment: Please add code tags around all pieces of code

Comment: Sounds like this is going to fail - unless the advertisements use a common set of techniques (i.e same classes etc) then I don't see how you can reliably or efficiently do this.

Comment: I think looking through the adblock+ code is good first move. But why do you need to do this using Selenium? Why not something like `wget` + `awk`?

Comment: @SiKing My aim to to identify in which dom object the adds are displayed and should be able to click them and lot of other automation tasks I have to perform . So selenium is the best tool I can use